# xlColumnClustered Chart Legend Has Wrong Range (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, charts, bar-chart

I am trying to create a series of 6 charts in a sheet, one after the other. The data looks like this:

[image]

The VBA looks like this:

```
Sub createEmbeddedClusteredBarChart()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim mySourceData As Range
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim myChartDestination As Range
    Set WS = ActiveSheet
    row_n = 16
    For ii = 0 To 5
       With WS
           Set mySourceData = WS.Range(WS.Cells(1 + ii * rown_n, 2), WS.Cells(row_n * (ii + 1) - 1, 4))
           Set myChartDestination = .Range(WS.Cells(1 + ii * row_n, 8), WS.Cells(row_n * (ii + 1) - 0, 8 + 10))
           Set myChart = .Shapes.AddChart2(Style:=-1, XlChartType:=xlColumnClustered, Left:=myChartDestination.Cells(1).Left, Top:=myChartDestination.Cells(1).Top, Width:=myChartDestination.Width, Height:=myChartDestination.Height, NewLayout:=False).Chart
           myChart.SetSourceData Source:=mySourceData
       End With
       myChart.SetSourceData Source:=mySourceData
    Next ii
End Sub
```

This almost does it right, but the legends of the charts don't look right for every chart after the first. See this example (red range):

[image]

and so on:

[image]

I see no way to set the range for the legend, and I don't understand why it is automatically trying to combine the cells all the way up to the top. What in my VBA needs to change to fix this?

Comment: Is it the code you show the one you copied from your workbook? If so, you firstly should add `Option Explicit` on top of the module keeping the code. In this way WBA will oblige you to declare all variables and you would find the typo from `Range(WS.Cells(1 + ii * rown_n, 2)` when setting `mySourceData`. I mean `rown_n` instead of `row_n`. I tried reproducing your problem, but my systemm, due to`Option Explicit`, asked about a non declared variable...

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo, as caught by FaneDuru. I had `rown_n` instead of `row_n`. Fixing it solved the issue.

Comment: `Option Explicit` is your friend. In the VB Editor, go to Tools > Options. Check "Require Variable Declaration" and while you're at it, uncheck "Auto Syntax Check". Then go to every module, and if it's missing `Option Explicit` at the top, type it in. Option Explicit will halt code execution and point out a compile error if you used an undeclared variable, for example, if you have misspelled a variable name. See [VB Editor Settings](https://peltiertech.com/vbaide-settings/).